# Confused about error while learning Polymorphism

Tags: java, methods, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

I'm learning polymorphism and I am getting this red line in my superclass and sublcass it's commented on my code:

```
    public class Animals {
  private String name;

  public Animals(String name) {
      this.name = name;
        }

  public void changeName(String name){
      this.name= name;
  }

  public String getName(){
      return this.name;  // 
  }

}
```

here is my subclass:

```
public class Dog extends Animals {
    private String colour;

    public Dog(String name, String colour){
        super(name);  
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    public void changeColour(String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }
    public String getColour(){
        return this.colour;
    }

}
```

Here is the other script with the main method:

```
public class AnimalPolyTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animals puppy = new Dog("homie", "black"); // constructor Dog cannot be applied to given types;
        puppy.getName();
        (Dog) puppy.getColour(); // not a statement

    }
}
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting these red lines
Edit: The code runs but nothing comes out.
Edit2: Fixed the classes.

Comment: a `void` method cannot `return` a value.

Comment: Your method `getName()` declares `void` (i.e. "no return type") as its return type but you try to return a `String`, the content of the variable `name`. That is incompatible. You will have to declare the method like `public String getName()`.

Comment: `public void Animals(String name)` is a method. To turn it into a constructor remove the `void`, so your base class only has the default constructor `public Animals()`, hence the constructor error

Comment: Usually polymorphism in Java has some special classes like `abstract class`. Can one of your classes be considered `abstract`? Also, perhaps review the constructor syntax again for classes https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: Also `Animal` (singular) is a better name for the class

Comment: @Nabz When you say "The code runs but nothing comes out" are you expecting some output? Are you expecting the output in a terminal window or in a debug window in an IDE like Eclipse? Also, on StackExchange, please don't edit your post to correct your code errors as you find them; it makes the answers below look wrong.

Comment: @Tophandour I am expecting an output im using netbeans, when the code runs all i get is run: built successful

Comment: @Nabz ok, you need to have some print statements. Look at this tutorial to learn how to do that: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html#run It looks like your code is *probably* working correctly, except for the fact that you don't have any print statements.

Comment: @Nabz specifically, you want `System.out.println("Your String Here");`

Comment: @Tophandour I think something is wrong with the java file itself, I made everything else a comment and wanted to see if it would print just System.out.println("Hello")  but it just said run: built successful but hello never came out. Edit: yeah something is wrong with the java file it self, I created a new code and things are printing out..strange

Comment: @Nabz maybe you should ask a separate question on how to get text to print out in NetBeans. I don't want to go on too long in the comments about this second issue because people frown on that. Please do upvote answers here that were helpful to you and possibly accept one that you think was most constructive in helping you solve your other problems, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animals class should look like this

```
public class Animals {
    private String name;

    public Animals(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void changeName(String name){
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

The problem you have is that your constructor had a `void` return type. Constructors should not have a return type. Secondly, your `getName()` method had a return type of void. To get it to work properly you need to declare what it's returning. Given this, I would leave it to you to implement the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors must not have return type, as it is implicit (a constructor for `Dog` obviously *returns* a `Dog`):

```
public Dog(...)
```

not

```
public void Dog(...)
```

The same applies for `Animals` of course.

And your `get` methods declare a `void` return type which is contradictory to the intent, so change to:

```
public String getName()...
public String getColour()...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `getName()` is set to have a return type of `void` and you're attempting to return a `String`. Change `void` to `String` in this method, and the red line should disappear there. You also have the same problem in `getColour()`.

In addition to this, you cannot have a return type on your constructors, so you should remove `void` on those.

Your line `(Dog) puppy.getColour();` is attempting to cast the `String` that is returned from `puppy.getColour()` to a `Dog` object. I believe that what you're trying to do is call `getColour()` on `puppy` but you noticed that it needs to be a `Dog` first. Try this instead: `((Dog)puppy).getColour();` so that you cast `puppy` to `Dog` and then you can call the method that you want.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]

I have annotated the problematic lines in your code.

```
public class Animals {
  private String name;

  /*
   * This is a method, not a constructor, because it has a return type.
   * Since there is no constructor, Java will automatically generate an implicit
   * `Animal` constructor for you -- one with no parameters.
   *
   * To fix: remove the return type.
   */
  public void Animals(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }

  public void changeName(String name){
      this.name= name;
  }

  /*
   * The return type should be String, not void.
   */
  public void getName(){
      return this.name;  // RED LINE: Unexpected return value
  }
}

public class Dog extends Animals {
    private String colour;

    /*
     * 1. A "super(...)" call only makes sense from within a constructor, but this is not
     * a constructor, due to the void return type.
     * 2. Java will automatically generate an implicit `Dog` constructor for you -- one with no parameters.
     * 3. Since the only Animals constructor is the implicit constructor, which has no parameters,
     * the "super(...)" call would fail even if this was a constructor.
     * 
     * To fix: Fix Animals, and remove the void return type.
     */
    public void Dog(String name, String colour){
        super(name);  // RED LINE: constructor Animals in Animals class cannot be applied to given types; 
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    public void changeColour(String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    /*
     * The return type should be String, not void.
     * 
     * To fix: change "void" to "String".
     */
    public void getColour(){
        return this.colour; //RED LINE: unexpected return value
    }
}

public class AnimalPolyTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*
         * The only Dog constructor is the implicit constructor, which has no parameters.
         * 
         * This will be fixed once Dog and Animals are fixed.
         */
        Animals puppy = new Dog("homie", "black"); // constructor Dog cannot be applied to given types;

        puppy.getName();

        /*
         * Dog.getColour() returns nothing (since its return type is void).
         * It makes no sense to try to coerce nothing to be of type Dog.
         * 
         * To call getColor(), you need to coerce puppy to be a Dog this way:
         * ((Dog) puppy).getColour();
         */
        (Dog) puppy.getColour(); // not a statement

    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed my classes taking out void where they shouldn't have been. Now I'm on the main method class but I am still getting nothing out of output even if I write System.out.println(puppy.getName()); I thought it would at least print out the name for the puppy. As for (dog) puppy.getColour(); i'm trying to get the output to show the colour of the dog, but that method doesn't exist in the super class since puppy is of the animal type, so instead I cast it with (Dog) so that it can now print out the colour

Comment: I tried running the code after correcting all the annotated errors, and `System.out.println(puppy.getName())` does print out "homie" for me. Make sure you have made all the suggested changes. I will add info to my answer about how to fix the coercion issue so that you can call `getColour()`.